# .htaccess rewrite code for dynamic URL (Joomla tpjobs)

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, joomla1.5

1.FROM : http://www.topcafirms.com/index.php/component/tpjobs/articletraineedetails/49

1.To : http://www.topcafirms.com/article/49

I m non-technical....pls let me know what to add in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You actually want:

```
/article/49 => index.php/component/tpjobs/articletraineedetails/49
```

Here's the `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/?$ /component/tpjobs/articletraineedetails/$1 [L]
```

**Note:** I'm not familiar with Joomla. It may need to further redirect the link. So the `L` flag might need to be removed.

Comment: I tried it but nothing happen.... :( currently...there is additional rewrite rule working...(as under)....can this have any reason for not workin                     RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1